# how to organize application settings and build GUI automatically based on settings class?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

my `c++` application has been growing and now I'm faced with a dozen of application settings (member variables of application class) and as many GUI elements representing these settings. In order to have a better control of all the options / settings, I was thinking to do the following:

1. create application settings class which will make it easier to keep track of all options.
2. remove GUI elements that represent settings / options from main GUI and move them into separate window.
3. generate the settings window automatically from settings class definition.

I'm wondering whether this approach makes sense. Are there any libraries that can build a GUI based on the class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [vartypes](http://code.google.com/p/vartypes/) project is supposed to help with just this.

It uses the QT framework to generate a GUI for your declared variables. Variables could be either declared within your code, or loaded dynamically from xml files.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I hadn't heard of this.